# CodeIgniter date - wrong time

Tags: codeigniter, date, time

I'm using:

```
date("d-m-Y h:i:s")
```

in my controller, but the time is later than actual time.
For example, now in my country it's 01:02, date return 20-06-2015 01:06:38.

How to fix it?

Comment: so your time is off by some minutes? if thats the case, then adjust the time on your server machine

Comment: @Mateusz Ji try adding in config.php like my answer says works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place timezone on the top of the config.php file above base_url

`date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Warsaw');`

Then refresh server

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Warsaw');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Base Site URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
| WITH a trailing slash:
|
|   http://example.com/
|
| If this is not set then CodeIgniter will try guess the protocol, domain
| and path to your installation. However, you should always configure this
| explicitly and never rely on auto-guessing, especially in production
| environments.
|
*/
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';
```

Answer (score 2):

1st Step :
Go to `config/config.php` and write

```
//specify your region 
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Warsaw');
```

2nd step: now you can use your time

```
date("d-m-Y h:i:s") //for 21/12/2010 20:12:00
date("h:i:s") //for 12:12:11 time only
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the hooks settings in your config file from TRUE to FALSE that should help with your issue.

Except if you have a very important need for the hooks to be enabled you should be very fine this way.

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

change to:

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
```

I hope this helps you.