# Date function result wrong time in CodeIgniter and date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore'); in Config file not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

Like the title, i have problem with date(Y-m-d H:i:s); function with give wrong time. I have changed config.php file with add date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore'); on top of the file and it is not fully working.

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');
```

However it working if i add it at the method/function that use date function as example :

```
function giveMyDate(){ 
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore'); 
echo(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')); 
}
```

Can anyone explain why if i add date_default_timezone_set in config.php not working? I must add it as global cause too much code that use date function.

The case above similar to here but i already try that suggestion but not working :
[CodeIgniter date - wrong time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948532/codeigniter-date-wrong-time)

Comment: `echo(date(Y-m-d H:i:s));` is that actually what you code is? or is it `echo(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));`

Comment: Sorry , i already updated the code @augwa

Comment: Can you update your code to provide what you're expecting vs what you're getting?

Comment: I add other reference that similat to my case, you can read it thank you @augwa

Comment: It would be helpful if you just added what's happening for your specifically.

Comment: plz try to put it in index.php

Comment: It's likely that `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');` isn't being run before your code. It's also possible that codeigniter somewhere along the way also sets this, which in turn causes your default to be overwritten.

Comment: I think that's already explain my problem thank you @augwa

Comment: @vikas-umrao : not working for me

Comment: have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882790/how-to-set-date-timezone-for-code-igniter-to-work-with-php5-3

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore'); put this in index.php root of the app and check

Answer (score 1):

have you tried **changing** **timezone** in your `php.ini` ?

```
[Date]
date.timezone=Asia/Singapore
```

more reference here http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php/setting-the-timezone-for-php-in-the-phpini-file

Comment: I can't change php.ini cause i don't have access to it (similar with shared hosting). @keith-asilom

Comment: sorry did not know you have access to php.ini maybe you could try placing ini_set('date.timezone', 'Asia/Singapore') at your index.php